# Oracle SQL, how can i use like operator in this way => like '%column name%'

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanna search for certain data with the a certain pattern. But I would like to do it as an user-input function, search for the pattern that i put in.

```
with user_input as(
select 'user input' usr_ip
from dual
)

select
*
from table
where column like '%usr_ip%'
```

I wanna get the result dataset of the column containers usr_ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would generally work...

```
with user_input as( select 'user input' usr_ip from dual )
select * from someTable, user_input where someColumn like '%'||user_input.usr_ip||'%'
```

But if your real question is how to get user input into a sql statement, well, that is not something to be done in SQL. There is no SQL statement or function to get data from the user directly. Mechanisms like host variables or dynamic sql can be used in the calling program to provide user input to the database.

Comment: Really appreciate for the answer, it works perfectly! I'm using a program which managed to have the user input function, I just need to merge the user input with the sql statement. I didn't think of the concatenate function but I'm still a little puzzled about this " '%'||user_input.usr_ip||'%' ". Why it's not in the way like  ' '%'||user_input.usr_ip||'%' ', which is adding one more single quotation marks on the outside?

Comment: You only need the single quotation mark for string literals. The `'%'` parts are string literals, but the whole expression  `'%'||user_input.usr_ip||'%'` is, well, an expression and does not need a further quotation mark.

Comment: @flyme2themoon Are you sure it works perfectly? It gives `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` because the sub-query factoring clause is not `JOIN`ed with (or queried in) the final `SELECT` (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/98sGgwg0)).

Comment: @MT0 you are right, fixed

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: @jarlh Aggreed, in general.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the sub-query factoring clause (a.k.a. CTE) and can simplify the query to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  column_name LIKE '%user input%'
```

If you have a pre-processor that allows you to enter user input via a function (because no such function exists natively in an Oracle database) then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  column_name LIKE '%' || your_user_input_function() || '%'
```

If you do want the sub-query factoring clause then you need to `JOIN` it to the query:

```sql
WITH user_input (usr_ip) AS (
  SELECT 'user input' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t.*
FROM   table_name t
       INNER JOIN user_input u
       ON t.column_name LIKE '%' || u.usr_ip || '%';
```

or use a sub-query:

```sql
WITH user_input (usr_ip) AS (
  SELECT 'user input' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  column_name LIKE '%' || (SELECT usr_ip FROM user_input) || '%';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u1RKXvKg)